# I would like to remove listitem

Tags: android, listview

I'm making a app which shows news. if I don't wanna show 'news_item1', how to remove it from list? is there no way to set invisible for 'news_item1'?

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// Log.e("www", "getView " + position);
v = convertView;
if (v == null) {
    int res = 0;
    if (mItems.get(position).iType == 0)
        res = R.layout.news_item;
        else
            res = R.layout.news_item1;
        v = inflater.inflate(res, parent, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
if (v == null) {
    int res = 0;
    if (mItems.get(position).iType == 0){
        res = R.layout.news_item;
        v = inflater.inflate(res, parent, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not very clear question, though, what I understand that you need to show items from index 1 to size of an array.

To do so, do the following:

in Adapter override getCount method and return size-1

in Adapter override getItem method and return arr[position+1]

Comment: Let me clear the question. I have listview which shows 'news_item(main news)' and 'news_item1(news related to main news)'. In listview, one main news and multiple related news are below. I don't wanna show related news, so I wanna remove related news from listview.

Comment: You can remove it at the time of add item in arraylist. And your adapter show only those items which are in arraylist.

Answer (score 0):

You should use setVisibility properties of the view as gone when you got position 1 of listview

```
v = inflater.inflate(res, parent, false);
v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: If I use setVisibility properties, 'news_item' is gone either. I just wanna remove 'news_item1'.

Answer (score 0):

Get the desired childview/listitem using list adapter and remove it from adapted, now populate the list again i.e.

```
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

u can visit this link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:visibility

in that goto android:visibility pane and check it out

android:visibility = “invisible”

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in the XML file.

```
android:visibility = "invisible"
```

In the Java code, use `textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`.